# How can I get text from a user using Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to create an automatic mailing system for a Google Spreadsheet.
I want to create a menu button that the user can press and get a dialog box with a big (paragraph-size) textbox to write his message in.

My problem is creating the right instance to be able to pass the user text input:

- I tried using `Browser.inputBox("title")`, but this only generates a 1-line text box.
- I tried using the `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt` method, but again this only generates a 1-line text box.

Any ideas on what class/method I should be using to be able to get the user's text message?

**EDIT**
here is another go, this time using shoeModalDialog() and html code.
i think its pretty close, but not working yet. Thoughts?

```js
function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('testHTML')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setWidth(600)
      .setHeight(400);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');
}


function jsGetText(text) {
  //do something with the string object
}
```

```html
<script>
function mySuccessFunction(textBox) {
  jsGetText(textBox.value)
}
</script>


<form method="post" >
    <textarea name="textBox" id="textBox" cols="60" rows="20" class="html-text-box"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="send" class="html-text-box" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(mySuccessFunction).withUserObject(document.getElementById('textBox')); google.script.host.close()">
    <input type="reset" value="cancel" class="html-text-box" onclick="google.script.host.close()">
</form>
```

Comment: If you want to have custom content for a dialog box using HTML, that can be done with [showModalDialog()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModalDialog(Object,String))  There is Modal and Modeless types which suspend or do no suspend server side code.  If this answers your question, let me know and I enter it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks Sandy Good, i actually did try that and had an HTML code to feature a big TextBox and a submit/cancel button. Problem is i failed to get the value of the textbox sent back when pressing Submit or to have a function called with the text value. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Oh, okay.  You need to use [withSuccessHandler()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)  Note that the function that is the success handler automatically captures the return value in the argument section of the function.  `mySuccessFunction(argReturnGetsCapturedHere)`

Comment: I gave it a shot, i edited the original question with what i wrote. Would appreciate your input. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The showDialog function looks good.  Don't put all the code into the `onClick()` attribute.  Remove `method="post"` from the form tag.  You don't want to send a POST request in this situation.  Use `Logger.log()` statements, and `console.log()` statements, and constantly be checking the Execution Logs for server errors.

### Code.gs

```
function jsGetText(text) {
  Logger.log('text: ' + text);
  Logger.log('text.length: ' + text.length);

  for (var key in text) {
    Logger.log('key: ' + key);
    Logger.log('value: ' + text[key]);

  };


  var objFieldOne = text['textBox'];
  Logger.log('objFieldOne: ' + objFieldOne);

  //do something with the string object

  return objFieldOne;
};
```

### testHTML.html

```
<script>
function fncGetUserTxt() {

  var objUsrInput = document.getElementById('idInputForm');

  /* for (var key in objUsrInput) {
    console.log('key: ' + key);
    console.log('value: ' + objUsrInput[key]);

  };
  */
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(mySuccessFunction)
    .jsGetText(objUsrInput); 

    //google.script.host.close()
};

function mySuccessFunction(textBox) {
  alert('Success! : ' + textBox);
};
</script>


<form id='idInputForm'>
    <textarea name="textBox" id="textBox" cols="60" rows="20" class="html-text-box"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="send" class="html-text-box" onmouseup='fncGetUserTxt()'>
    <input type="reset" value="cancel" class="html-text-box" onclick="google.script.host.close()">
</form>
```